# Directory recursion and symlinks

Tags: unix, recursion, directory, symlink

If you recursively traverse a directory tree by the obvious method, you'll run into trouble with infinite recursion when a symlink points to a parent directory.

An obvious solution would be to just check for symlinks and not follow them at all. But that might be an unpleasant surprise for a user who doesn't expect what behaves for other purposes like a perfectly normal directory to be silently ignored.

An alternative solution might be to keep a hash table of all directories visited so far, and use this to check for loops. But this would require there to be some canonical representation, some way to get the identity, of the directory you are currently looking at (regardless of the path by which you reached it).

Would Unix users typically regard the second solution as less surprising?

If so, is there a way to obtain such a canonical representation/identity of a directory, that's portable across Unix systems? (I'd like it to work across Linux, BSD, Mac OS, Solaris etc. I expect to have to write separate code for Windows.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most frequently ignored API in this field would be

#### [nftw](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CBYQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Flinux.die.net%2Fman%2F3%2Fnftw&ei=R6BsToLfOo6hOqvAjMMF&usg=AFQjCNEU2qtss-1N8Qu4Ec7vZHRkHoFTWw&sig2=yA_YQx022OpU3-OlAYF20A)

Nftw has options to avoid it traversing symlinks. It has much more advanced capabilities than that. Here is a simple sample from the man page itself:

```
#define _XOPEN_SOURCE 500
#include <ftw.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdint.h>

static int
display_info(const char *fpath, const struct stat *sb,
             int tflag, struct FTW *ftwbuf)
{
    printf("%-3s %2d %7jd   %-40s %d %s\n",
           (tflag == FTW_D) ?   "d"   : (tflag == FTW_DNR) ? "dnr" :
           (tflag == FTW_DP) ?  "dp"  : (tflag == FTW_F) ?   "f" :
           (tflag == FTW_NS) ?  "ns"  : (tflag == FTW_SL) ?  "sl" :
           (tflag == FTW_SLN) ? "sln" : "???",
           ftwbuf->level, (intmax_t) sb->st_size,
           fpath, ftwbuf->base, fpath + ftwbuf->base);
    return 0;           /* To tell nftw() to continue */
}

int
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int flags = 0;

    if (argc > 2 && strchr(argv[2], 'd') != NULL)
        flags |= FTW_DEPTH;
    if (argc > 2 && strchr(argv[2], 'p') != NULL)
        flags |= FTW_PHYS;

    if (nftw((argc < 2) ? "." : argv[1], display_info, 20, flags)
            == -1)
    {
        perror("nftw");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

See also

- [Directory recursion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7377596/directory-recursion/7377707#7377707)
- http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Walk_a_directory/Recursively

Comment: The man page for nftw says to use the `fts` functions instead, which are also available on both Linux and BSD (macOS) and work more efficiently. See also my answer below (which doesn't provide more info, though)

Comment: Thanks @ThomasTempelmann for adding perspective. I never actually use this function in practice (I suppose I might in a "quick" program that needed to be in C. I did once ace an interview question with it :)). It's good to re-read man-pages when re-using snippets after 10 years!

Answer (score 3):

The absolute path of the directory is such a representation. You can get it with the `realpath` function, which is defined in the POSIX standard, so it will work on any POSIX-compliant system. See `man 3 realpath`.

Answer (score 2):

Not only symlinks, but hard-links as well. Not very common, but not forbidden. (Only root can hardlink directories)
The only thing that is canonical is {device_number, inode_number}. But network filesystems can misbehave.

Answer (score 2):

This problem of identical files must be solved by many applications, for example a checker for file doublettes (indentical contents, different names) and utilities acting on whole directory hierarchies, like `tar`.

A good implementation wouldn't want to give false positives for hard linked files and symlinked files, either through symlinks to parent directories or to files.

The most portable approach to solve this is identifying files by looking at the POSIX stat/fstat functions and the `struct stat` they fill in with `st_dev` and `st_ino` members.
A real world implementation of a file dupe checker in C employing this strategy is [samefile](http://www.schweikhardt.net/samefile/) (a different implementation of which was a winning entry of the 1998 [IOCCC](http://www.ioccc.org/main.html) :-)

Answer (score 2):

There is also the Linux/BSD function `fts_open()`.

It gives you an easy-to-use iterator for traversing all sub directory contents while also detecting such symlink recursions.

In fact, the man page (on macOS) for `nftw` says that it's an old function which is now superceded by the fts API I mention here:

> These functions are provided for compatibility with legacy code.  New code should use the fts(3) functions.

Answer (score 1):

Since you haven't specified what language you're working with (if any), let's start with just the shell: if you're on a system with GNU `readlink`, just use `readlink -f <path>` to canonicalize it.

If you're on a Mac (which has a non-GNU `readlink` that behaves differently), see [How can I get the behavior of GNU's readlink -f on a Mac?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1055671/how-can-i-get-the-behavior-of-gnus-readlink-f-on-a-mac) for the way to accomplish the same task.

The other option is to use inode ids to track unique files (via `stat` or similar), but that'll require first following all of the symlinks anyway (since symlinks themselves do have their own unique inode id), and the simplest way to follow all of the symlinks is, well, `readlink`.

---

Alternatively, many programming languages have bindings to the POSIX `realpath` function, which essentially performs the same function as `readlink -f` (but as a library call). For instance, Python has [`os.path.realpath()`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html#os.path.realpath), C has it as a function in `stdlib.h`, et cetera.

If you're already working in  a language that has such a function, using it is highly recommended, since you'll often get cross-platform compatibility for free (assuming your language is cross-platform).